# Python script for downloading images and videos from social media websites using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to try one python script which downloads the images and videos from the given social media website url given while running

Like when I run python XXX.py url,path
It should download only the images and videos with their respective formats and should store in the path specified while running

Can anyone provide me a road map to achieve this task?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it is a url directly to the source. So something like (theoretical url) `https://cdn.facebook.com/path/to/wanted/file.png` and no login required to open this link (depending on profile / page / group privacy policy settings), then common **cURL**, **wget**, **requests** (python module), and other tools, whether system commands and programs or libraries, should suffice.

If login is required and there is no possibility to have header data (Authorization, X-some-auth-header or cookie) and it is necessary to iterate with the login and retention session, then Selenium is the solution. However, if I have the necessary header data, then the easier paths mentioned above can be used.

Hypothetically (I never downloaded files with Selenium): In case of selenium, it is necessary to open the source of images / videos directly and then copy the content of the page.

```py
browser.get("https://cdn.facebook.com/path/to/wanted/file.png")
data = browser.page_source

with open("/path/to/save/file.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)
    pass
```

Update: 
I looked at the Internet, I found [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver/6317#6317). It should work. Thus, the top snippet works when the picture / video is displayed, but the download does not start.

For videos, it can be quite tricky over some streaming HTTP and the like. If it becomes more complicated, the solution would be to use or inspire with `youtube-dl` to support countless video sources for download. Including login solutions.

Update 2:
Based on comment:
*for example I had a link like this facebook.com/hkrugby Now I need to download videos and images sepeartely from this url using python script how?*

3 options:

1) Find all the elements (img, video) using the Selenia interface and collect the URLs they link to.

2) Take the page source - HTML - and either find a regular expression or other way of searching to find the right elements (img, video) and extract URLs from them.

3) Take the page source, but parse it (for example, Beatiful Soup), then get links from the elements again.

He sets the problem for things like "infinite scroll" and "lazy loading", where the page is done continuously by scrolling down. Resources are not loaded until you are zoomed in / on the page. Depending on the implementation of the technology, often there is an element such as `data-url="htttps://...'`, which is copied to the URL when the script is started and the resource is loaded. Or, the original element is temporarily replaced by another to prevent the resource from loading unnecessarily.

Scrolling can be done via JS in the browser, but you never know how far you have to scroll and if we are talking about a page or group, so we can scroll and find the url that we have already downloaded. Then it would be nice, for example, to keep an url index that has already been downloaded.

Some suggestions on how to do this:

1) Open the page - `browser.get("...")`

2) Save the current page_source to a temporary variable

3) Scroll down and wait X seconds (depending on the speed of the machine and the Internet, some time when we are sure that the content is already full)

4) Verify the current page_source against the variable from step 2, if different then repeat the steps from step 2 again, repeat until page_source matches the variable from step 2

5) Find elements on the page (by CSS selector, XPATH, etc)

6) Extract any url or other metadata needed for download

7) Then download the extracted url

**Optimization Enhancements:**

We store index of downloaded URLs, load it when restarted and interleave page scrolling by searching elements and URL parsing. If we find the URL we have already downloaded, there is no need to scroll anymore.

**Update 3:**
[Demo](https://github.com/geekmoss/Selenium-crawl-and-download-demo)

Comment: for example I had a link like this https://www.facebook.com/hkrugby/ Now I need to download videos and images sepeartely from this url using python script how?

Comment: @stack I modified the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: do you have any sample script for these type of tasks?

Comment: @stack I don't have anything at the moment, but in a few hours I will have time to try and make a demo. :)

Comment: Ok Geekmoss Can you please make a demo and share me here If you dont mind mean while I will also try

Comment: @stack Here: https://github.com/geekmoss/Selenium-crawl-and-download-demo

Comment: how did you done it @Geekmoss

Comment: @stack What exactly do you think?

Comment: If I give like this python XXX.py url,path  It should download the pictures and videos from the facebook or instagram or twitter url

Comment: I am asking you is your script is for my requirement or not I am sorry I didnt understand thats why I asked you @ Geekmoss

Comment: Yes, but there is no login and some authentication to the site where there is a restriction when the user is not logged in (see Instagram restrictions on unsigned, private policy on facebook and others). But here you have a skeleton to download all images and videos from a page based on some selector, so it can be easily expanded. Do not be angry, but Stackoverflow is not primarily about writing code for others. I am happy to help, but I cannot write everything for you.

Comment: Okay Thankyou Now what changes can I do in the script given by you for achieving my requirement @ Geekmoss